# Android refresh google map after turning on location

Tags: java, android

I have a google map in my project. First of all, I check whether the user has location enabled. If the user does not have location enabled, a dialog box pops up asking them to enable location. When the user accepts this prompt, he or she is redirected to the settings page where they can enable location.

The problem is after enabling location and press back, the map remains in its previous state, i.e. does not zoom to the user's current location.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't know the android apis but there surely is an event that is triggered when the user switches back to your app. You could juste check the location service there again

Comment: @NielsNet I have gone through the apis and searched vastly online but I have not gotten a concrete solution.

Comment: there seems to be an `onResume`-event that you could use.

Comment: you can achieve it by OnResume. its pretty simple. just clear the map and do whatever you want on onResume

Comment: Check my answer to view a sample example of implementation @ChrisOtaalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reload the map on the method onResume:

edit (i am assuming that you have declared the mGoogleMap object on class scope):

```
    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();

     if(googleMap != null){
        googleMap.clear();

        // add the markers just like how you did the first time
     }
    }
```

Comment: How to you actually reload the map? Could you have a code sample for reloading the map?

Comment: i have edited my answer, as you didn't shared your code but the principle is you need to clear and add the markers.. hope that i helped

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement LocationListener

```
public class FragmentMap extends SupportMapFragment implements LocationListener
{
GoogleMap mGoogleMap_;

[...]

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{  CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.builder(mGoogleMap_.getCameraPosition());
   builder.target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
   mGoogleMap_.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(builder.build())); // CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(...) if you need to zoom too
}

[...]
```